# How is the breakdown of lactose regulated at the gene level?

Tags: gene-regulation, operons

How is the breakdown of lactose regulated at the gene level?

This is my answer: Without lactose in the cell, the repressor protein binds to the operator and prevents the read through of RNA polymerase into the three structural genes. When there is lactose in the cell, lactose binds to the repressor. This causes a structural change in the repressor and it loses its affinity for the operator. Thus, RNA polymerase can then bind to the promoter and transcribe the structural genes.

But I'm not sure if this is right...

Comment: Welcome to Bio. Homework questions are warmly welcomed here at Bio, barred you show your research efforts so far. We are not here to simply do the homework for you. If you can provide us with the things you *do* know, we can fill in the gaps for you. Good luck! I'm putting this question on hold for now. After you've made edits to *this* post we can re-open it for you. Please don't make another separate question out of it, because then other users cannot see the question history.